# Gmail subaddressing ('plus sign' addressing) in Android

Tags: android

This is a very simple issue. I'm trying to put a link to an email address in a TextView, using Html.fromHtml.

```
body.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:emailaddress+subaddress@gmail.com\">Contact</a>"));
```

When that link is clicked, a new email is addressed to "emailaddress subaddress@gmail.com". Notice that the plus symbol has disappeared. I've tried this:

```
body.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:emailaddress"+'+'+"subaddress@gmail.com\">Contact</a>"));
```

and

```
body.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"mailto:emailaddress&#43;subaddress@gmail.com\">Contact</a>"));
```

to the same result.

Anyone know how I can get the link to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `+` sign is one URL-encoded form of a space (the other is `%20`). To encode a literal `+` sign in a URL, you need to escape it in the same way - in this case as `%2B`

Comment: Well, I feel stupid. :P Totally forgot about that. Thanks a ton.